# How should I connect my new WiFi Smart Switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Installing WiFi switch on the last switch to the right. Where do the 2 black and 2 white wire connect.

See existing wiring in picture below:

[image]

Comment: What make and model is the wifi switch?

Comment: It is aTP wifi switch

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/TP-Link-Required-Requires-Assistant-HS200/dp/B01EZV35QU/ref=sr_1_1?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1519061709&sr=1-1&keywords=tp+link+switch&dpID=41OF7SHV1VL&preST=_SY300_QL70_&dpSrc=srch

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice video at [that link](https://www.amazon.ca/TP-Link-Required-Requires-Assistant-HS200/dp/B01EZV35QU/ref=sr_1_1?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1519061709&sr=1-1&keywords=tp%20link%20switch&dpID=41OF7SHV1VL&preST=_SY300_QL70_&dpSrc=srch) which covers things pretty well. You connect the blacks to the two blacks that connect to your current switch.

The white from the new switch can be bundled with the cluster of white neutrals in the box, though it appears that the nut on it is already quite full. You might need to split the bundle and connect two smaller bundles with a jumper.

The green ground wire connects to the bare ground wire bundle in the box.

Comment: Could it be added to the smaller bundle of white?

Comment: Yes, if it's on the same circuit. I didn't see that one initially.